# Attempting to Install Numpy with PyPy v7.3.1, errors surrounding building wheels

Tags: python, c++, numpy, pip, pypy

I've been at this for a while, looking everywhere for answers but I still have no solution.

I'm attempting to install numpy with PyPy via Pip on Windows.
After ensuring Pip, upgrading Wheel, Setuptools, Pip, and running the command: pip3 install numpy - I get a long error where it looks like it's trying to use all sorts of compilers to install numpy but fails. It spits an error:

```
    C:\Users\kadth>pip3 install numpy
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.19.2.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\pypy3.exe' 'c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\kadth\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpic_f4ajo'
         cwd: C:\Users\kadth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ciif09v5\numpy
    Complete output (190 lines):
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'c:\\programdata\\chocolatey\\lib\\pypy3\\tools\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
      FOUND:
        language = c

    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win32-3.6
    creating build\src.win32-3.6\numpy
    creating build\src.win32-3.6\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    C:\Users\kadth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ciif09v5\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\kadth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ciif09v5\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\kadth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ciif09v5\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\kadth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ciif09v5\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\kadth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ciif09v5\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\pypy3.exe' 'c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\pypy3\tools\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\kadth\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpic_f4ajo' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Now, I have tried installing Microsoft Visual C++ build tools 14.1 +. I've tried pretty much every combination and uninstalled an reinstalled both Microsoft Visual C++ build tools and PyPy using a variety of methods such as through chocolatey. Setuptools, Wheel and Pip are all updated to the latest version.
Installing Numpy through regular Python pip works, and it seems it works because it grabs the variant that already has wheels so it doesn't have to use the C++ compiler. So I think my problem is centered around build tools not operating properly.

I have also set the location of rc.exe, and cl.exe to my path, but that didn't solve anything either.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Then next version of NumPy will support PyPy win32 wheels. You can get the preview [here](https://anaconda.org/scipy-wheels-nightly/numpy/files), and it can be installed via `pypy3 -m pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/scipy-wheels-nightly/simple numpy`.

Comment: Hi there. Whilst this is a good fix to just get Numpy, I need to also install a number of other libraries such as Pandas. Which after installing Numpy using your method, still gives me very similar errors around building wheels and installing dependencies. Is there a way to get the C++ build tools working properly so I can compile the binaries/wheels on my machine? Thanks.

Comment: I think the error is misleading (it comes from distutils). Try installing some other version of Visual Studio, like the latest 2019. Much of this is out of our control, it will work the same on CPython as it does on PyPy. Another thing to do is to try to encourage conda to provide support for PyPy on windows.